# Graphing the DAG generated by make?

Tags: linux, makefile, directed-acyclic-graphs

My understanding is that when `make` executes, it generates a DAG internally to represent all the dependencies in the project.  Is there a way to get at that DAG and graph it, say using something like graphviz?

I'm using gnu make on Ubuntu 8.04.

**EDIT**

I just ran across these tools called [mamdag](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/mamdag.html) and [mamdot](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/mamdot.html).  They're supposed to work with both nmake and gnu make, but I can't seem to find the options to get gnu make to spit out the mam file.

[It can be downloaded here](http://www.research.att.com/sw/download/) - these packages:

INIT
ast-base
ast-gpl

Just found this article by Glenn Fowler at AT&T [describing the MAM language](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/mam/) and the mamdot tool.

It seems like you have to patch gnu make for this to work, although I'm not 100% certain yet.

Maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 4):

You should try using [`Makefile::GraphViz`](http://search.cpan.org/~agent/Makefile-GraphViz-0.18/lib/Makefile/GraphViz.pm)'s [gvmake](http://search.cpan.org/~agent/Makefile-GraphViz-0.18/script/gvmake) utility to create the graphs you want

Comment: +1 for interesting, but what I really want is to visualize gnu make's internal DAG.

Comment: `makesimple`, which the gvmake doc suggests you use, gets the output from `make --print-data-base` and parses that. it probably contains enough information about the internal DAG, though I can't really confirm that

Answer (score 1):

For the code side of things, [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will produce dependency diagrams between source and header files, if that is what you are interested in, without the use of make.

Comment: No, I actually want a dump of `make`'s internal DAG.  It's a way of proving that the build setup for a particular project is broken and needs to be reworked.  Along the lines of the paper, "Recursive Make Considered Harmful", http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf