# Build a makefile dependency / inheritance tree

Tags: c, linux, embedded, makefile

Apologies if I explain this badly or am asking something bleeding obvious but I'm new to the Linux kernel and kinda in at the deep end...

We have an embedded-linux system which arrives with a (very badly documented) SDK containing hundreds of folders of *stuff*, most folders containing a rules.make, make, make.config or some variation of... and the root folder containing a "master" makefile & rules.make which mean that you can, from the root folder, type "make sysall" and it builds the entire package.

So far so good, but trying to debug it is a bit of an issue as the documentation will say something like:

"*To get the kernel to output debug messages, just define #outputdebugmessagesplz*"

OK, but some of these things are defined in the "master" make/rules file, some of these are defined in the child make/rules/config files, some are in .h files... and of course it's far nicer to turn these things on/off from the "top" make.config rather than modifying individual .h files and then having to remember to turn them off again.

So I thought it would be a useful thing to recursively build a tree, starting from the master "make" file and following everything it does, everything that gets defined or re-defined, etc... but there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing that?

I assume I am missing a "make" option here that spits this info out, or a usage of the makefile/config that will just work?

Comment: `make -n` will not run any commands, just print those that *should* run.

But since `make` provides many implicit rules, and isn't procedural in nature, I fear you're a bit out of luck here.

Comment: Make -n doesn't work in this case as the "root" makefile calls other "makes", for example "make all" then invokes "make clean; make kernel; make bootloader; make uimage..." and many of those invoke other sub-cases... Unless there is some way of cascading the make -n parameter to all of the other makes?

Comment: Make just isn't build to *output* the dependency graphs it is working with. In part *because* of the behaviour you describe - calling sub-makes. Another point where make will fail to tell you the whole story is when it's delegating to external tools. Makefiles of my making tend to depend on `gcc` to generate header dependency information for C/C++, `latexmk` for LaTeX needs, and so on. I'm afraid there's no easy help for your problem.

Comment: I find it quite amazing that no-one in the *nix community has come up with a tool to do this in some way or another. If I ever get this project done maybe I should try to build one!

Comment: You will find that `make` is *quite* a complex beast, not made easier in the least by the fact that there are several different versions of it around. But good luck nevertheless.

Comment: You can try to create an alias make='make -n', it should create the recursivity you may need.

Comment: Getting the dependencies right might not be an option... So what about  putting together a little script that inserts
`
    #ifndef outputdebugmessagesplz
    #define outputdebugmessagesplz
    #endif
` (on separate lines ;-) 
at the top of each source and header file?

Still you would have to remove the maybe still existing "hard coded" `#define outputdebugmessagesplz` that are already there...

To remove debuggin later you could `sed -i 's/outputdebugmessagesplz/outputdebugmessagesplz_not/g'` on all files in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is not uncommon. When developing for embedded systems, you might encounter many custom systems that solve a problem in a specific way. As people already commented on your question, there's no easy way to generate a dependency graph for your makefile structure/framework. But there are some things you can try, and I'll try to base my suggestions based on your situation. Since you've said:

> *Im new to the Linux kernel and kinda in at the deep end...*

and

> *We have an embedded-linux system which arrives with a (very badly
>   documented) SDK containing hundreds of folders of stuff*

You could try the following things:

- If your SDK is provided by a third-party vendor, try contacting them and get some support.
- SDK's usually provide an abstraction to work with several components without a deep understanding of how each one of them really works. Try to pinpoint your problem, like if you want to customize *only* the kernel configuration, you could find the linux kernel folder on your SDK (assuming your SDK is composed of a set of folders with things like libraries, source code of applications and stuff, one of them might be the kernel one) and run ***make menuconfig***. This will open a ncurses-based configuration GUI that you can navigate and choose kernel options.
- As people already pointed out, you can try to run **make -n** and check the output. You could also try to run **make -p | less** and inspect the output, but I don't recommend this since it will only print  the  data  base (rules and variable values) that results from reading the makefiles. You would have to parse this output to find out what you want in it.

Basically, you should try to pinpoint what you want to customize and see how this interacts with your SDK. If it's the kernel, then working only with it will give you a starting point. The linux kernel has its own makefile-build system, named **kbuild**. You can find more information about it at the [kernel's Documentation folder](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/).

Besides that, trying to understand how makefiles work will help you if you have a complex makefile structure controlling several components. The following are good resources to learn about makefiles:

[GNU Make official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

[O'Reilly's Open Book *"Managing Projects with GNU Make"*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/)

Also, before trying to build your own tool, you can check if there's an open source project that does what you want. A quick search on google gave me this:

- [makegrapher](https://code.google.com/p/makegrapher/)

Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032269/backtrace-for-gnu-make) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947821/graphing-the-dag-generated-by-make). You might find useful information from people that had the same problems as you did.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you use [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) (mpp), it comes with [makeppgraph](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/gallery/) (mppg) to get this.  You get many kinds of views, graphically or textually.  Because the result is typically huge, you can tailor it with some simple Perl programming.

Comment: @Daniel this looks like a very helpful project. I might even start using it personally. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Work your way slowly through this, often makefiles you find in the wild are written in atrocious style...