# GNU make - accelerate non-parallel makefile without modification

Tags: c++, build, makefile, gnu-make

I have a project consisting of a set of makefiles that CANNOT be run with `make --jobs=N` because the dependencies are not specified tightly enough for `make` to correctly execute the recipes in correct order (ie I get race conditions).

I am currently using Huddle, by Electric-Cloud.com, and it does exactly what I need: it parses the makefile and then executes the jobs in parallel and accounts for the unspecified dependencies.

Question: is there a free or free-er thing that does this?

Yes I know I could re-write the makefiles but project management says "no way".

**UPDATE #1**

I understand that I'll have to do *some* work to get functionality similar to Electric-Cloud's functionality.

I know that Electric-Cloud parses the makefile(s) to find the dependencies so wouldn't the same thing be accomplished using `makedepend`?

I'm thinking:

1. Run `makedepend` on existing makefiles
2. Feed in the output using `include <makedepend.output>`
3. `make all --jobs=64`

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out `makedepend` is specific to C/C++: it merely runs the pre-processor on source files and parses any `#include` statements; not what I need.

I need what this guy is asking for:
[Build a makefile dependency / inheritance tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563302/build-a-makefile-dependency-inheritance-tree)

**UPDATE 3**

The makefile "dependency graph generator" actually already exists

http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2012/11/visualizing-dependencies-of-makefile.html?m=1

but that's not going to help me.

Many of my recipes create directories which are used by other targets' recipes, effectively making them implicit prerequisites.

The graph dependency tool at above URL works by parsing the build log's statements but those statements don't indicate the implicit dependencies.

Even if I try to run my makefile with `--dry-run`, the build fails because some of the recipes that aren't executed - cause it's a dry run - create directories that other invocations of `make` need simply to 'pretend execute' a recipe.

**UPDATE 4**

Electric-Cloud has made Huddle - 4 local cores, non-clustered - free for anyone forever.
Furthermore, they output an .xml file that lists each job's dependencies so I can use it to fix my makefiles compatible so they're compatible with the `--jobs` option.

Comment: You don't have to rewrite the existing makefiles to add dependency information. You can add that all in one or more additional makefiles if you can specify the information manually (or auto-generate it). That can be as "automatic" as you can be smart about discovering the dependencies. That's, ultimately, what Electric Cloud has put serious time/work into doing, sorting out these details from *inside* a make process.

Comment: @EtanReisner how do I auto-generate it?

Comment: That depends *entirely* on what the dependencies are and how you can discover them. I believe at least some of EC's tools figure this out by literally tracing `open`/etc. system calls during the build to construct a profile and do this over a number of fake and then real and then re-run builds to ensure they get it right. If you can parse your files for dependencies that's one thing. If you need to run them for it (dynamic plugins, assets. etc.) that's another. There's no "simple" solution here (that's why EC has a meaningful product).

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried running 'make --dry-run' but it failed because some of the recipes create directories which are effectively implicit prerequisites to other targets. Yeah. I guess Electric-Cloud is definitely special.

Comment: None of the targets should have run in that case so things shouldn't have failed for missing directories/prerequisites. Auto-generated makefiles/etc. will still need to have their rules run so those *could* fail even with `--dry-run` if they were **really** written badly.

Comment: @EtanReisner the place where my `--dry-run` fails is in `make -C dir1`. `make` tries entering a **directory** to execute a **makefile** that were both generated via a recipe from another target. Since `--dry-run` doesn't execute the recipes that create these two things, running `--dry-run` on the non-existent **makefile** in the non-existent **directory** will fail. In short, yes I know these makefiles were horribly written; I work for a services firm that inherited a project from totally diff co. My past 5 questions have to do with fixing these! Lol. I'm glad that Electric-Cloud exists.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, that's not a poorly written makefile issue that's just a poor design decision issue. That's not avoidable really (without writing the rules to understand `--dry-run`). I assume the recipe line is `$(MAKE) -C $<` or similar. Because make runs lines with `$(MAKE)` even during `--dry-run` (which is often what you want). You can probably work around that but it would take some work/re-writing.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently using Huddle, by Electric-Cloud.com, and it does exactly what I need: it parses the makefile and then executes the jobs in parallel and accounts for the unspecified dependencies.

I actually don't know about these tools, but can't you provide them with a *super makefile* under your control, that clarifies the inner dependencies of the various targets?

You probably just have to add some indirection level for these (imported?) projects directory structure and another `Makefile`.

Comment: Probably. But Electric-Cloud works without providing anything additional. I'm looking for a tool like that.

Comment: @Adrian Well, you somehow introduce a _main makefile_ for that tool, didn't you?

Comment: Yes there's a main makefile . . . but the only work that I'm doing is replacing `make all` with `emake all`. I accept that I'll have to do SOME additional work for a free-er solution than Electric-Cloud. @EtanReisner's comment to my main question is on the right path: I need a tool to auto-generate the dependencies and then feed that into my makefile.

Comment: I tried editing your answer but guess it was rejected but add the following and I'll accept it. "Yes I always knew that's what I had to do; the question was HOW to obtain that information using tool rather than manually. The answer is Electric-Cloud Huddle: for each job, it outputs dependencies but more importantly, even the implicit dependencies and even more specifically, filesystem I/O dependencies. I can use this information to manually add inter-job dependencies so that I can just `make` to run my build in parallel"